# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar informes con tablas dañadas?

Tags: linux, asterisk

Resulta que las tablas de la base de datos Asterisk ("cdr" y "queue_log") están corruptas.

Al ejecutar el comando de recuperación se queda indefinidamente intentando recuperar la tabla pero jamás se logra hacer la recuperación.

Comment: ¿Qué es Dyalogo? ¿Cuál es la finalidad de la pregunta-respuesta siendo como es la respuesta tan específica?

Comment: DYALOGO es un producto de software para callcenter, www.dyalogo.com la idea de este post y de varios que se van a hacer es proveer soluciones a problemas de este producto.

Comment: en tal caso lo pertinente sería añadir una etiqueta. Sin embargo, no parece que la pregunta tenga que ver con este producto de software, sino con Asterisk, por lo que lo considero innecesario. ¿Eres empleado de esa empresa o usuario de su producto?

Answer (score 0):

Hola si el comando de recuperación no funciona puede que la tabla tenga muchos millones de registros y por eso la demora del comando.

Si en definitiva la recuperación no funciona, se puede eliminar la tabla y volverla a crear, luego desde el Master.csv se recupera la informacion.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `asterisk`.`cdr` (
  `id` INT ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `calldate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '2011-01-01 00:00:00',
  `org_unique_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `uniqueid` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `clid` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `src` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dst` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dcontext` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `channel` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dstchannel` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastapp` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastdata` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `duration` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `billsec` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `disposition` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT '',
  `amaflags` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `accountcode` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT '',
  `userfield` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '',
  `id_huesped` INT NULL,
  `id_troncal` INT NULL,
  `endcall` DATETIME NULL,
  `id_ruta_saliente` INT NULL,
  `id_ruta_entrante` INT NULL,
  `linkedid` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `sentido` TINYINT(5) NULL,
  `robot` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `procesada` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `grabacion` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `desborde` INT NULL COMMENT '1 - Buzon\n2 - Numero interno\n3 - Numero externo.',
  INDEX `calldate` (`calldate` ASC),
  INDEX `dst` (`dst` ASC),
  INDEX `accountcode` (`accountcode` ASC),
  INDEX `uniqueid` (`uniqueid` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `ix_lastapp` (`lastapp` ASC),
  INDEX `ix_orguid` (`org_unique_id` ASC),
  INDEX `ix_grabacion` (`userfield` ASC))
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
```

Luego de eso se deben hacer las acciones correspondientes a la recuperacion de la informacion usando las herramientas de DYALOGO.